# selenium tests aplication path problem test not run on selected url

Tags: command-line, selenium, selenium-rc

I try to start my selenium test using command line but test are fired to **http://mycomputer** and not to **http://mycomputer/myapplication**

```
D:\projectsnet\Production\MyWebTests\tools\selenium-server>java -jar selenium-
server.jar -Dhttp.proxyHost=mycomputer -Dhttp.proxyport=4444 -htmlSuite "*firefox" "ht
tp://mycomputer/myapplication/" "D:\mypathtotestssuites\0001-testsuite.html" "c:\temp\result.html"
```

In test cases I have got link

```
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://mycomputer/myapplication/" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.

If you are doing development against http://mycomputer/myapplication/ then I would recommend that you do http://mycomputer as your baseURL and then add

```
open | /myapplication/
```

To the top of your tests.